# The lone builder

Tags: strategy, computer-puzzle

You are a lone builder. You have to build a city on a 10x10 initial empty grid. You can place:

- a street, which is a blue cell on the top of any cell,
- a tomato shop, which is a red cell on any cell having a street in one of his 4-neighbors,
- a small house, which is a green cell on any cell having a street and a tomato shop in two of his 4-neighbors,
- a tall building, which is a yellow cell on any cell having a street, a tomato shop and a house in three of his 4-neighbors.

These rules are valid during the construction step only: if a cell is replaced by another one, it has to comply the rules, but its neighbors can break them.

Below is an example of a possible city:

[image: The city achieved currently by our builder]

The question is easy:

**How many yellow tall buildings can you build in the city, and in how many steps?** An answer is considered better than another one if it maximizes the number of buildings, or if the number is the same but it does it in a lower number of steps.

For instance, if you would be given a 3x3 city, you could build 4 buildings in 12 steps:

[image: How to build a 3x3 city in 12 steps]

For the little story, I got inspired from a now unavailable Android game: [com.amusetime.buildingtower](https://www.google.fr/search?hl=en&q=com.amusetime.buildingtower&gws_rd=cr&ei=fZpbVpDiNsXxaKPrkNAO)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### <s>56</s> 57 yellow squares / 149 steps

> First place the blue, red and green squares like in the following three images (the black X marks new squares):
> [image]
> Then fill the green spiral with yellow buildings, starting top left. Add the 4 green buildings from the middle image. Finally fill the remaining yellow buildings from the right image.
> [image]

Comment: Did you use some logic to solve this question ? can you prove that your answer is optimal ?

Comment: Did you use dynamic programming by any chance to solve this ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal It's 5 years ago, and I don't even remember the question. But I'm pretty sure I solved it by hand, and the spiral movement was the main idea. Obviously because of that I can't prove it's optimal.

Answer (score 2):

First approximation of an answer:

**46 Yellow squares in 125 actions.**

Let's label the rows 0 - 90 and the columns 0 - 9, thus defining each square in the grid from 00 - 99.

1) Color blue mostly in pairs - 00, 01, 04, 05, 08, 09, 22, 23, 26, 27, 40, 41, 44, 45, 48, 62, 63, 66, 67, 80, 81, 84, 85, 88, 89.  Note that square 49 is *not* colored. This takes 25 actions.

2) Additionally, color in 10, 19, 39, 50, 59, 93, 95, and 96 blue - this takes 8 actions.

3) Color in 90, and 99 red - this takes 2 actions (note that 80, and 89 are blue).

4) In rows 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8, color all the un-colored squares red (again excluding 49) - this takes 24 actions.

5) color in the following squares green - 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 31, 33, 35, 37, 51, 53, 55, 57, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 91, 97.  This takes 20 actions.

6) Color in every square vertically or horizontally adjacent to a green square as yellow, excluding 09 and 90.  This takes 46 actions.

Done.  All squares except 49 and 94 are colored at this point.

Comment: Your estimate of 50 seems to be an actuality of 48.

Comment: Last step is I only 48 steps since only 48 yellow obey the rule of 3...

Comment: Righty, missed two different edge cases - looks like 4 of my yellows get cut off as a result.

Comment: I think only 2 yellow

Comment: in addition to the corners (which obviously only have 2 adjacent squares) I found that on the two of my edges that contain yellow, there was no combination of interwoven colors that allows them every other square - the closest I could get was losing one per side.  Feel free to find something I missed, though.  I make no claim that this is the ideal answer - just that it's good enough to be worth posting as a baseline.